# Linq to SQL: Lock on table entry

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012

I have several instances of application (.Net), which use the same table.
Each of the application instance take the first entry in the DataBase table and change the status (additional row in the table) of entry from "Pending" to "Processing", after that application starts update data in the 3rd party system.
How can I implement my logic to be ensure that second instance will not take this "Pending" entry in the same time ? 
I am using Linq To Sql approach, and would like to avoid conflicts in the DataBase with the same database entry.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to take the first entry that isn't locked and lock it to signal to other instances that someone else is working on that instance. 
Afterwards, perform the operations you need on the unrelated tables and when you're finished unlock the instance. The overall code should look something like this:

```
var instance = db.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Status == "Pending");
instance.Status = "Processing";
// Save changes so the other clients can see that this row is locked
db.SaveChanges();
// Perform custom logic
// And mark the instance as finished
db.Table<Entity>().Attach(instance);
instance.Status = "Finished";
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit**

In order to avoid multiple applications getting the same instance at the first time, you need to wrap the query and update into a transaction. This way all other applications will wait for the transaction to be committed before getting the results:

```
Entity instance;
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    instance = db.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Status == "Pending");
    instance.Status = "Processing";
    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented exactly as you recommended. But I am wondering if it could be when several applications trying to update entry status at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. And, is it possible to cover this functionality with Integration Tests ? I would like to be ensured that several application do not take the same entry at the same time.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just make two or more simultaneous requests.